# The claims exchange returned HTTP error response that could not be parsed

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm new to API Connectors of Azure, Azure user creation like orchestration steps are all working except Azure API Connector cannot parse the HTTP Content OK response. I'm using below code:

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost, Route("REST_API_ENDPOINT_BEING_CALLED_BY_AZURE_API_CONNECTOR")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SaveUserDetails([FromBody] SomeEntity entity)
    {
         // saving and everything works fine with entity..
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK,$"Azure Account is linked}");
        else
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "Account could not link");
    }
```

Are these Task[IHttpActionResult] and Content(HttpStatusCode.OK,$"Azure Account is linked}"); combination right? It worked for Postman but not sure why it is not working for Azure. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it works for the below combination:

Task[HttpResponseMessage]:

return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);